# Android Proguard Obfuscation of serialized object

Tags: android, serialization, proguard

I have a serialized object which is saved in DB. This is in the previous version.

```
public class Book implements Serializable{

  String id;

}
```

In my current version I have changed the data type of `id` to `int`. When I update my app, I get the deserialized object back from DB but the `id` is `0`.

I have tried to use `applymapping` to map to the older version. But of no use.

I have also added these lines in my **progaurd.cfg**:

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
  static final long serialVersionUID;
  private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
  !static !transient <fields>;
  private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
  private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
  java.lang.Object writeReplace();
  java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Can someone help me here? Thanks.

Comment: how do u save the object to DB? because I do understand you´re using serialization and deserialization and that won´t work for preexisting records as for String is an object and won´t read that to be an int.

Comment: not even if serialized as a nul ended char strip it will work for as long as you don´t read it back manually and parse it to int

Comment: The object is converted to byte[] and then saved to DB.

Comment: by serialization... I do understand... then this has nothing to do with your proguard settings. The preexisting records have a String instead of a plain int. You *must* convert them to the new format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `readObject` method and try reading the new format field by field and fall back to old one on error.

This guy here has an example with validation of the data read, also: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45